# Get selected object from TreeView

Tags: application-development, quickly, glade

I've been working on a minor (first time) app with quickly and hit a hurdle - how do I get the selected row (the data) from a TreeView? The data to the TreeView is passed from a list of files in a directory, and I need to know which rows were selected (and thus which files were). What is the best way to do that?

Here's the current code:

```
    self.treeview = self.builder.get_object("treeview")
    select = self.treeview.get_selection()
    select.connect("changed", self.on_tree_selection_changed)

def on_tree_selection_changed(selection):
    model, treeiter = self.treeview.selection-get()
    if treeiter != None:
        print "You selected", model[treeiter][0]
```

Comment: The code above won't work because the signal passes the class instance (`self`) as the first argument to the function. Also the function call is incorrect. See my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/treeview.html

You can get the selection on an event by connecting a selection object to an event:

```
select = tree.get_selection()
select.connect("changed", on_tree_selection_changed)
def on_tree_selection_changed(selection):
    model, treeiter = selection.get_selected()
    if treeiter != None:
        print "You selected", model[treeiter][0]
```

Edit:
To set this up within a window class, use the following code:

```
class MyTreeView....
    ....Other Stuff...
        self.treeview = self.builder.get_object("treeview")
        select = self.treeview.get_selection()
        select.connect("changed", self.on_tree_selection_changed)

    def on_tree_selection_changed(self, selection):
        model, treeiter = selection.get_selected()
        if treeiter != None:
            print "You selected", model[treeiter][0]
```

Edit2: If you want to have multiple rows selected you need to use `Gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected_rows()` which returns a list of `Gtk.TreePath` instances of all selected rows.

Comment: Hm, I used this, but what I get every time something is seleceted is: "TypeError: on_tree_selection_changed() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)".

Comment: Edit your question with the relevant code that fails.

Comment: Try putting in an extra argument in the function definition( `def on_tree_selection_changed(selection,data):`) Then in the function print out a representation of what each is to see (eg: `print repr(selection)` or `print repr(data)`).  One of them should be the correct data structure (ie the Gtk.TreeSelection) to use. Posting the code would help too.

Comment: I added the code to my question.

Comment: Thanks! But this now results in a different error: "Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_tree_selection_get_selected: assertion `priv->type != GTK_SELECTION_MULTIPLE' failed".

This works when I set it to single select, so I guess multi-select treeviews require different stuff. Sorry for not saying that in my post.

Comment: Yes... See the link above in the tutorial it states you need to use Gtk.TreeSelection.get_selected_rows() instead.  Adding that to the answer now

Comment: Does the job, thanks - now how would I write a function that when called, just selects the NEXT row?